# Ruby on rails Lock edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The problem arose.
I need to implement pessimistic locking records.
I wish that until at least one user is in editing the record, no one else can go to edit the record or delete it.
As it can be implemented in Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 0):

yeah sure it can be done. add a new boolean attribute in model called let say `lock` when someone hits `edit` action of a record update lock to `true`. and in `update` action set it to false after successful updation.

Comment: I thought about it, but what if the person who went to the editing changes are not applied, but simply closed the page?

Comment: u need to do few things in that case. force editing user to complete the editing -> by saving edit url to user session and redirect every time on that url when he try to move somewhere else without completion.
when other user want to edit check who locked this record his session exist or expired. if expired allow him to edit.

Comment: Is there an example of how you can check whether there is a session?